# Avoid Division by Zero in Sigmoid function

Tags: python, deep-learning

With : https://nbviewer.org/github/ImadDabbura/blog-posts/blob/master/notebooks/Coding-Neural-Network-Forwad-Back-Propagation.ipynb as reference
I am trying to build a Vanila Deep Learning Code.
I wonder how is division by zero avoided in the sigmoid funtion.

```
def sigmoid(Z):
"""
Computes the sigmoid of Z element-wise.

Arguments
---------
Z : array
    output of affine transformation.

Returns
-------
A : array
    post activation output.
Z : array
    output of affine transformation.
"""
A = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-Z))

return A, Z
```

Comment: 1 plus a value which tends to zero as Z -> inf. is never zero....

Comment: What is the expectation if you can explain with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder how is division by zero avoided in the sigmoid function.

For `1 + exp(-Z)` to be zero, `exp(-Z)` would need to be `-1` which won't happen because `exp` is always positive for all real numbers. `Z` is a real number in the context of neural networks.

Comment: Zero is a Real Number, and what is Z =0, exp(Z) / exp(-Z) =1. ?

Comment: @user2458922 If `Z = 0`, then `sigmoid(Z) = 1 / (1 + exp(0)) = 1 / (1 + 1) = 0.5`
Also, the sigmoid function `1 /  (1 + exp(-x))` is defined for all real numbers, you're not going to find a real number x that has an undefined `sigmoid(x)`